# How do I return to a higher nesting level in ReST?

Tags: restructuredtext

In restructured text, how do I write:

```
Chapter 1:
    Section 1:
       Some section 1 text
    Section 1.1:
       An aside
    Section 1:
       Back to section 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [section hierarchy](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#sections) is decided by the order in which the section titles are encountered. This means that there is no way to add paragraphs to the parent section that do not belong to a child section, once the first child section has been added.

I recommend restructuring the text (no pun intended) or using footnotes. Literal blocks are another possibility.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to convert a large document in another format that is structured that way, so no ReST for me.